# type script merge objects left and right

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, merge, javascript-objects

how can I create a function to merge the two objects.

1. First argument: Object to be merged (left)
2. Second argument: Object to be merged (right)
3. Third argument: Specify which property is left on the merged object. ('concat', 'left', 'right'), 
   default is concat

**concat:** Leave all properties of two objects   
 **left:** Property of returned object is property of object of first argument only   
 **right:** The property of the returned object is only the property of the object of the second argument

```js
const input1 = {a: 'la', b: 'lb'};
const input2 = {a: 'ra', c: 'rc'};

// concat
mergeObj(input1, input2, 'concat'); // output: {a: 'ra', b: 'lb', c: 'rc'}
// left
mergeObj(input1, input2, 'left'); // output: {a: 'ra', b: 'lb'}
// right
mergeObj(input1, input2, 'right'); // output: {a: 'ra', c: 'rc'}
```

Comment: Your outputs seems to contradict the above statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function mergeObj which based on the three conditions return the desired output

**First case- Concat**: You need to merge two objects. You can simply use `Object.assign` to do that

**Second case- left**: Map over the first object keys and if the value is present in second object set that else return the first object value itself.

**Third Case- right** Simply return the second object

```js
const input1 = {a: 'la', b: 'lb'};
const input2 = {a: 'ra', c: 'rc'};


function mergeObj(inp1, inp2, type) {

  if(type === 'concat') {
    return Object.assign({}, inp1, inp2);
  } 
  if (type === 'left') {
     return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(inp1).map(([k, val]) => ({[k]: inp2[k] || val})));
  }
  if (type === 'right') {
    return Object.assign({}, inp2);
  }
}
// concat
console.log(mergeObj(input1, input2, 'concat')); // output: {a: 'ra', b: 'lb', c: 'rc'}
// left
console.log(mergeObj(input1, input2, 'left')); // output: {a: 'ra', b: 'lb'}
// right
console.log(mergeObj(input1, input2, 'right')); // output: {a: 'ra', c: 'rc'}
```

Comment: @d.Foo Don' t you think the answer that you accepted doesn't give the output as you mentioned in your question. Or did you just ask a wrong question

Comment: @d.Foo this is not what you asked in question `concat: Leave all properties of two objects    left: Property of returned object is property of object of first argument only    right: The property of the returned object is only the property of the object of the second argument`  correct me if i understood something wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a [**switch statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and [**destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const input1 = {a: 'la', b: 'lb'};
const input2 = {a: 'ra', c: 'rc'};

const mergeObj = ( input1, input2, prop ) => {
  switch(prop){
    case 'left' : return {...input1};
    case 'right': return {...input2};
    default: return {...input1,...input2}
  }
}


console.log( mergeObj(input1, input2, 'concat') );
console.log( mergeObj(input1, input2, 'left') );
console.log( mergeObj(input1, input2, 'right') );
```

Comment: that's awesome very short answer too , I have two more questions I will post now that I think you can help me with !

Comment: This doesn't give the output that the OP mentioned in the comments of his snippet

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri `concat: Leave all properties of two objects    left: Property of returned object is property of object of first argument only    right: The property of the returned object is only the property of the object of the second argument`  i considered these lines and answered.

Comment: property of first object may mean accept the keys of first object only and merge the values with the second